# unsigned int to const char* in C

Tags: c, type-conversion

I'm using a function which receives a const char*.

```
long hex2long(const char* hexString)
```

I have that hexString in unsigned int format and need to convert it to const char* to use that function.

I have also tried to use strtol() but it's the same problem.

Any idea?

This is the function:

```
static const long hextable[] = 
{
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,         // 10-19
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,         // 30-39
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0,  1,
         2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, -1, -1,         // 50-59
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,         // 70-79
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 10, 11, 12,         // 90-99
        13, 14, 15, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,         // 110-109
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,         // 130-139
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,         // 150-159
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,         // 170-179
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,         // 190-199
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,         // 210-219
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,         // 230-239
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
};


long hex2long(const char* hexString)
{
        long ret = 0; 

        while (*hexString && ret >= 0) 
        {
                ret = (ret << 4) | hextable[*hexString++];
        }

        return ret; 
}
```

Comment: You can just use the unsigned int as the argument, no conversion needed, like so:

Comment: long hex2long(unsigned int hexString)

Comment: I have an HEX number in unsigned int format and want to convert it to decimal format.

Comment: Oh I see you need a string of numbers, just use an array of unsigned ints as your argument and you're set

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confused.  Your function parses the hexadecimal representation of a number and returns the value as a `long`.  You should stop parsing when you encounter a non-hexadecimal digit, and you could ignore any leading white space characters.  The library function `strtol()` does just that, with a value of `16` for the last argument (conversion base).

What else are you trying to achieve?